# this jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m using jQuery for my drupal site. I can't add class to current element by using jQuery.

I put this addclass inside a if condition with alert. Alert has working fine. But addclass not working.

```
if (jQuery(".explore_degree_widget_area li a").has(":contains('Associates')")) { 
    jQuery(this).addClass('icon_associate');
    alert('Yes');
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You can only get $(this), if you are using it inside any event.

Comment: @DharaParmar Wrong. You can use `$(this)` inside `.each()` iteration and callback functions in methods like `.text()`, `.html()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If condition would be always true, since **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)** returns filtered jQuery object. Also **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)**  avoid text nodes, it's only check on it's descendant, You need to use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** .

```
jQuery(".explore_degree_widget_area li a").filter(":contains('Associates')").addClass('icon_associate');
```

or use combined selector

```
jQuery(".explore_degree_widget_area li a:contains('Associates')").addClass('icon_associate');
```

Comment: There is no need in `.has()`: combine it in the selector.

Comment: @BhavanKumarNatarajan : glad to help :) you need to use `filter()` not `has()`

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the context but not to the element. Use the following:

```
jQuery(".explore_degree_widget_area li a:contains('Associates')")
    .addClass('icon_associate').each(function() {
        alert('Yes');  // if you really want to have it
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".explore_degree_widget_area li a:has(:contains('Associates'))").addClass('icon_associate');
```